# Bytes waiting in pipe

Tags: c, linux, numbers, byte, pipe

I am writing a remote terminal application and i use pipes to take data from a child process' stdout/stderr to then send it to a client. Specifically, I am running Linux, and I don't really care about portability (if the solution is Linux-only, it's OK).

I need to know how many bytes have currently been written to, but not yet read from, the pipe. I was Googling for a long time and couldn't find an answer. I need to read as many bytes from the pipe as possible without blocking.

Is this possible? Thank you for help.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, at least not in a portable manner, but if you explain *why* you need to do that there may be other alternative solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to attempt a read and count how many bytes you get. `recv` with `MSG_PEEK` can do that.

Your best bet will be to set your read end of the pipe to non blocking and then just read ahead. If your file descriptor is set to non blocking, you `read` on it and the pipe is empty then you well get `EAGAIN` error in `errno`. This will indicate to you that the pipe is still open, but just empty at the moment.

You can set your file descriptor to non block with

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) & ~O_NONBLOCK);
```

Then read:

```
while (read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
    if (errno == EAGAIN) {} // buffer currently empty
    else if (errno) {perror("read")} // an error happened
}
```